# How to override the functions of SortedKeyValueIterator interface in Accumulo?

Tags: java, hadoop, accumulo

I am trying to create a custom iterator, but since there are no tutorials available, I looked at the code provided at the Accumulo github page.

There I found that all classes implement the SortedKeyValueIterator and override its functions.

What is the role of these functions and what should be the approach when overriding these funcions when creating a new class that implements SortedKeyValueIterator.

This is the sample code of the RowFilter class that I was trying to understand .

```
 public void init(SortedKeyValueIterator<Key,Value> source, Map<String,String> options, IteratorEnvironment env) throws IOException {
super.init(source, options, env);
this.decisionIterator = new RowIterator(source.deepCopy(env));
}

 public SortedKeyValueIterator<Key,Value> deepCopy(IteratorEnvironment env) {
 RowFilter newInstance;
 try {
       newInstance = getClass().newInstance();
     } catch (Exception e) 
      {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
  newInstance.setSource(getSource().deepCopy(env));
  newInstance.decisionIterator = new RowIterator(getSource().deepCopy(env));
  return newInstance;
   }
```

I want to know, what does this code do, and how should I override these functions if i want another class to implement the SortedKeyValueIterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with a look at the Javadoc on SortedKeyValueIterator -- http://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/apidocs/. That's a good starting place for what each method is supposed to do.

A good analogy in writing an iterator is to think of your Accumulo table (which the iterator is operating on) as a single-linked list (in sorted order). next() moves to the next node in the list and seek() moves forward/down skipping zero to many nodes. init() provides any necessary configuration (your iterator is likely running in the Accumulo server) from both the Accumulo table configuration and the client. deepCopy() should duplicate the exact state of the current iterator into a new instance (similar to Object.clone()).

I can also provide two examples of custom iterators:

- https://github.com/joshelser/accumulo-column-summing/

  - Performs an intermediate sums over numbers that occur in a given column family
  - Requires a final summation client-side
- https://github.com/joshelser/RowsWithoutColumns

  - Only returns rows that do not contain a provided set of columns
  - Uses the WholeRowIterator serialization methods to return multiple key-value pairs as a single Key-Value pair (requires deserialization on the client)

You can also take a look at other provided "user-facing" iterators in Accumulo http://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/iterators/user/package-summary.html

Comment: Some important additional bits: seek() stages the first key/value pair in the range seek'd as the "top" key/value. next() stages subsequent pairs. So, you can assume that the caller will call getTopKey()/getTopValue() immediately after a seek(), and then again after each next() call.

Also, Consider extending WrappingIterator instead, as it implements the basics.

Comment: Thank You for providing a clear explanation of the functions!!

Comment: Happy to help. If you'd like, you can also file an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa and we'll try to get the docs updated in the next release.

Comment: Can you further explain the order in which these functions are called? Thanks.

Comment: A rough outline is: init(), seek(), repeated(next(), getTopKey() && getTopValue()). seek() might be called after any next() is called. e.g. seek(), next(), next(), next(), seek(), next(), seek(), next(), next(), seek(), etc. Would be happy to improve documentation if you would like to file a ticket!

Comment: As per my current understanding, I think that the functions of the SortedKeyValueIterator are called implicitly by the TServer.

How can I explicitly call seek function after next() function as described in your comment above.

For example, seek(), next(),next(),next(),next(), seek().

I also filed an issue regarding the same. Please have a look at that too.

Here is the link:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ACCUMULO-3633

Comment: Thanks so much. Getting good reference documentation at Apache will help greatly. The methods I outlined are what the TabletServer itself calls given the state (the current Key-Value). SKVIs are similar to Java Iterators in that respect -- someone else is calling the methods for you, and your implementation just has to adhere to the intended effect of each method.